# On click run GET request inside JavaScript parsing a JavaScript variable. Laravel framework

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I have a dropdown checklist that manipulates an array inside JavaScript.
Once the dropdown checklist selection is complete.  The array is called uniqueYears.

```
function myFilter() {
var requestData = JSON.stringify(uniqueYears);

   console.log(requestData);
   //logs correct json object
   var request;

   request = $.ajax({
       url: "/admin/award/filter",
       method: "GET",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {data : requestData}
   });}
```

I would like to send that array to my controller. where it checks and returns all the items that satisfy those conditions

```
public function getReportByYear(Request $request){
  $awards = Award::all();
  $nominations = Nomination::all();
  $unique_Years = DB::select('SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) AS uniqueYears FROM nomination group by uniqueYears  ');
  $countNoms = DB::select('SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at) AS uniqueYears, count(id) AS countID ,award_id from nomination group by award_id HAVING uniqueYears IN ');
  return view('admin.awardReport')->with('nominations', $nominations)->with('awards', $awards)->with('unique_Years' ,$unique_Years)->with('countNoms',$countNoms);
}
```

currently i am stuck with this error http://localhost/admin/award/filter?data=%5B%222014%22%2C%222015%22%5D 500 (Internal Server Error)

Any help getting past this error and getting to where i want to be would be appreciated !

here is the route i am using

```
Route::get('/admin/award/filter','AdminController@getReportByYear');
```

Comment: is that your `uniqueYears` in `var requestData = JSON.stringify(uniqueYears);`  variable passed from controller to view

Comment: No, the script is in one of the views. I want to pass it to the controller